# Spring Tool Suite can't import spring library classes

Tags: java, spring, maven

windows 8.1 64bit, jdk 1.8 64bit, spring tool suite 3.8.1 (64bit) installed--- how can i remove red lines from import library files

image link :: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsKWh.png

Comment: make sure you have build the project properly and all the maven dependencies were updates/resolved while building. Check whether you can find spring libraries under "Maven Dependencies" on the project explorer located at left side of STS IDE.

Comment: I have already done this and i figure out that  "spring-boot-test-autoconfiguration-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar" is empty but files are present in \.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\1.4.0.RELEASE . So why spring tool suit is unable to add these files during build???

Comment: can you try removing the directory *".m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\"* and issue the following command :
`mvn -U clean install|deploy`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a maven project. In such a project the libs (dependencies) are controlled mavens pom.xml

- If you have not done jet, then add the needed dependency declartions to pom
- Then click on your project "demo" with the right mouse button, and click on  Maven/Update Project...

A typical minimal pom.xml needed an simple spring-boot-web project looks like this (you can find a lot of other boot poms at https://spring.io/guides/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.your.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>           
</project>
```